# Mobile: Edits sometimes send you to "glitch screen" after submission

Tags: bug, android-app

I recently suggested an edit to one of my question's answers, because it needed reworded better. However, after submitting it, instead of getting a "Your edit was just suggested" toast notification, I got a different screen with a title "How to simulate session cookies in mobile sessions?". There were two top buttons: "Edit" and "Suggest", and a back button at the top.

The edit worked the second time I suggested it.

[image: Image of bug (link)]